# WP7 AAC MediaStreamSource

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, audio-streaming, aac, mediastreamsource

Does anybody have any implementations of MediaStreamSource for playing music in AAC coding?

Very very need.

Thanks.

Comment: Bump: Does anyone have any solution for this - I'm trying to play AAC content from a memory stream in WP7.

Comment: Peregrine, if you yet need a solution contact me and I will give you it. I already implemented MediaStreamSource myself.

Comment: Hi Roman, can you please post your MediaStreamSouce implementation here?